# how can i convert index to datetime in pandas?

Tags: pandas, indexing, time-series

i have index like this

```
Index(['00:00:00', '00:15:00', '00:30:00', '00:45:00', '01:00:00', '01:15:00',
       '01:30:00', '01:45:00', '02:00:00', '02:15:00', '02:30:00', '02:45:00'],
      dtype='object', name='time')
```

and need to convert it to datetime %H:%M:%S format 
How can i change it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
idx = pd.Index(['00:00:00', '00:15:00', '00:30:00', '00:45:00', '01:00:00', '01:15:00',
       '01:30:00', '01:45:00', '02:00:00', '02:15:00', '02:30:00', '02:45:00'],
      dtype='object', name='time')
```

For `DatetimeIndex` need some date, by default is added today:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(idx))
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-25 00:00:00', '2018-01-25 00:15:00',
               '2018-01-25 00:30:00', '2018-01-25 00:45:00',
               '2018-01-25 01:00:00', '2018-01-25 01:15:00',
               '2018-01-25 01:30:00', '2018-01-25 01:45:00',
               '2018-01-25 02:00:00', '2018-01-25 02:15:00',
               '2018-01-25 02:30:00', '2018-01-25 02:45:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)
```

Or is possible add custom date:

```
print (pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01 ' + idx))
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:15:00',
               '2015-01-01 00:30:00', '2015-01-01 00:45:00',
               '2015-01-01 01:00:00', '2015-01-01 01:15:00',
               '2015-01-01 01:30:00', '2015-01-01 01:45:00',
               '2015-01-01 02:00:00', '2015-01-01 02:15:00',
               '2015-01-01 02:30:00', '2015-01-01 02:45:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Another solution is create `TimedeltaIndex`:

```
print (pd.to_timedelta(idx))

TimedeltaIndex(['00:00:00', '00:15:00', '00:30:00', '00:45:00', '01:00:00',
                '01:15:00', '01:30:00', '01:45:00', '02:00:00', '02:15:00',
                '02:30:00', '02:45:00'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)
```